# Free public hosted database model - conceptually like github public repos

Tags: database, cloud-service

Are there any cloud database hosts that will host data to be shared publicly?  What I am looking for is conceptually similar to the Github or BitBucket concept where free users are allowed to host public repositories for free with the idea that it becomes a public resource.

I have a few projects that I would like to develop but do not have the time and resources to try out all of the different platforms out there while hoping that the one I pick will be easy to scale up when the time comes.